# Why does my chainWebpack in vue.config.js only work the first time after I change it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, loader

I'm using VueJs with a NodeJs Server on Windows. I want to implement a JavaScript Worker with the worker-loader module.

---

I have implemented a chainWebpack rule in my vue.config.js file, but it only works the first time I build the devServer using 'npm run serve' in my console.

When I add the rule, my test worker is loaded properly and responds to messages. When I restart the devServer, I get a mime type error when the worker is loaded.

Then, if I change the chainWebpack function in any way, i.e by changing the rules name, the rule is applied correctly again.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('worker-loader')
      .test(/\.worker\.js$/i)
      .use('worker-loader')
      .loader('worker-loader');
  }
};
```

I would like the rule to work every time I start the devServer, without the need to edit it every time I restart the server.

Is this some kind of caching issue that can be solved with a config value?

Answer (score 0):

Your config is fine, just add this line:

```
config.module.rule('js').exclude.add(/\.worker\.js$/)

config.module
      .rule('worker-loader')
      .test(/\.worker\.js$/)
      .use('worker-loader')
      .loader('worker-loader');
```

Now two loaders wouldn't fight over the same js file anymore

I know it's a year late, but might help someone else